# C# multiple records against the branch object

Tags: c#, oop

Customer record is added against a branch (of some grocery store ) it visits. If the customer visit multiple branches, then it is added against the multiple branches with the different ID's. Now my Question is how can i have only one record of the customer, no matter which branch it visits and how many branches it visits.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console47
{
    class Customer
    {
        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string CustomerTelNo { get; set; }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console47
{
    class Branch
    {
        public Guid BranchID { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public string BranchAddress { get; set; }
        public string BranchTelNo { get; set; }

        public List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();


        public void AddCustomer()
        {
            var customer = new Customer();

            Console.Write("\nEnter No of customers you want to Add: ");

            var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease remember to Enter input in the following order:\n");


            for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1-Customer Name:   2-Customer Address:   3-Customer Telno.:   4-Customer Email:   5-:Branch Name:\n");
                customers.Add(new Customer()
                {

                    CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    CustomerName = Console.ReadLine(),
                    CustomerAddress = Console.ReadLine(),
                    CustomerTelNo = Console.ReadLine(),
                    CustomerEmail = Console.ReadLine(),

                });

            }
            Console.WriteLine("***************************");

        }
        public void SearchCustomer()

        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter the name of the customer to find out which branch it is related to:");

            var Cname = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var Customeritem in customers)
            {
                if (Cname == Customeritem.CustomerName )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer ID:{0}\nCustomer Name:{1}\nCustomer Address:{2}\nCustomer Tel. No:{3}\nCustomer Email:{4}\n", Customeritem.CustomerID, Customeritem.CustomerName,Customeritem.CustomerAddress,Customeritem.CustomerTelNo,Customeritem.CustomerEmail);
                    Console.Write("\nCustomer found");
                }
                else if (Cname != Customeritem.CustomerName)
                {
                    Console.Write("Customer Not found");
                }
            }

        }

        public void DeleteCustomer()
        {

            Console.Write("To delete customer, enter name of the customer:");
            var Cname = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (customers[i].CustomerName == Cname)
                {
                    customers.RemoveAt(i);
                    Console.Write("Customer found and deleted");
                    break;
                }
                else if (Cname != customers[i].CustomerName)
                {
                    Console.Write("Customer Not found");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console47
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /***********Add branches************/

            List<Branch> branches = new List<Branch>();


            var branch = new Branch();

            Console.WriteLine("************************");
            Console.WriteLine("Total Branches of Lidel:");
            Console.WriteLine("************************\n");

            var branch1 = new Branch()
            {

                BranchID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                BranchName = "lidel1",
                BranchAddress = "ejbyvej 27",
                BranchTelNo = "55223366",

            };
            branches.Add(branch1);

            var branch2 = new Branch()
            {

                BranchID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                BranchName = "lidel2",
                BranchAddress = "kirkevej 45",
                BranchTelNo = "77885544",

            };
            branches.Add(branch2);
            var branch3 = new Branch()
            {

                BranchID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                BranchName = "lidel3",
                BranchAddress = "kirkevej 12",
                BranchTelNo = "553366611",

            };
            branches.Add(branch3);


            for (int i = 0; i < branches.Count; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\nBranch ID:{0}\nBranch Name:{1}\nBranch Address:{2}\nBranch Telno.{3}\n", branches[i].BranchID, branches[i].BranchName, branches[i].BranchAddress, branches[i].BranchTelNo);
                Console.WriteLine("************************");
            }



            /***********Add, delete, search customer in specific branch************/

            int choise;
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease choose from the following option:\n");

        UserChoise:

            Console.WriteLine("\n1: Add Customers:\n2: Search Customer:\n3: Delete Customer:\n4: Display total no of customers in All Lidel Branches:\n5: Press enter to exit:\n");
            Console.Write("Your input is: ");
            choise = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("***************************");

            switch (choise)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter the Branch name where you want to add the customer: ");
                        var BranchInput = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (BranchInput == branch1.BranchName)
                        {
                            branch1.AddCustomer();
                        }
                        else if (BranchInput == branch2.BranchName)
                        {
                            branch2.AddCustomer();
                        }
                        else if (BranchInput == branch3.BranchName)
                        {
                            branch3.AddCustomer();
                        }
                        else if (BranchInput != branch.BranchName)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\nBranch doest not exist, Please enter again.\n");
                        }


                        goto UserChoise;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        foreach (var bitem in branches)
                        {
                            bitem.SearchCustomer();
                            Console.Write(" in branch " +bitem.BranchName+".");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                        goto UserChoise;
                    }

                case 3:
                    {
                       foreach (var item in branches)
                        {
                            item.DeleteCustomer();
                            Console.Write(" in branch " + item.BranchName+ ".\n");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                        goto UserChoise;

                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                        foreach (Branch bitem in branches)
                        {
                            foreach (Customer citem in bitem.customers)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer ID:{0}\nCustomer Name:{1}\nCustomer Address:{2}\nCustomer Telno.:{3}\nCustomer Email:{4}\n", citem.CustomerID, citem.CustomerName, citem.CustomerAddress, citem.CustomerTelNo, citem.CustomerEmail);
                                Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                        goto UserChoise;
                    }
                case 5:
                    {

                        Console.Write("Enter the Branch name to find its customers: ");
                        var BranchInput = Console.ReadLine();


                        foreach (Branch item in branches)
                        {
                            if (BranchInput == item.BranchName)
                            {
                                foreach (Customer citem in item.customers)
                                {

                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer ID:{0}\nCustomer Name:{1}\nCustomer Address:{2}\nCustomer Telno.:{3}\nCustomer Email:{4}\n", citem.CustomerID, citem.CustomerName, citem.CustomerAddress, citem.CustomerTelNo, citem.CustomerEmail);
                                        Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        goto UserChoise;
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ll have to change your code to add an existing object to the branch, not create a new one. How to do this is too broad for this site, but it is not that complicated by itself. You’ll just have to think how to handle the user input for it

Comment: `goto UserChoise;` This should be **banned** from your mind. Really, please never use label/goto. Code become impossible to maintain.

Comment: Agreed. `goto` belongs in the 1980s, at best

Comment: Anyway what you want is what in relational database terms would be called a many-to-many relationship - i.e. a customer can be associated with many branches, but equally a branch can be associated with many customers. Have a single list of customers which is global to all branches, and just associate an existing customer with a particular branch when needed.

Comment: @Cid absolutely yes.  Anytime I'm writing something and see that `GoTo` would fix a branching problem I'm having, I know immediately that my design is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @ADyson. how would i implement idea of yours?? And association of the customer with the branch will be defined upon its creation. Now how do i do that ??

Comment: @Cid: It's offtopic for the current question, but `break` and `continue` are effectively `goto` statements that we've come to accept now that they have a different name and more limited applicability. I do agree that `goto` should be strongly avoided, but it seems an overstatement to (permanently - not just while learning) _universally ban_ `goto`, unless you also want to ban `break` and `continue`.

Comment: @Flater I never use `break` (but in switch case) nor `continue`, I prefer using others logics to properly leave some scopes

Comment: @Cid: More often than not, avoiding `break` (in an iteration) results in effectively iterating through the rest of the collection while ensuring nothing happens, which is irrelevant processing. The same is true for `continue` in scope of one iteration. Not using them simply increases nesting as you'll use an `if` statement that effectively achieves the same result anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **unique** customer can visit **multiples** branches.

An **unique** branch can be visited by **multiples** customers.

This defines an **Many-To-Many** relation.

In database, this results that kind of table structure :

**customers**

```
id | someDatas
---+----------
 1 | ...
 2 | ...
 3 | ...
```

**branches**

```
id | someDatas
---+----------
 1 | ...
 2 | ...
 3 | ...
```

**customerbranch**

```
idcustomer | idbranch
-----------+----------
 1         | 1
 1         | 2
 2         | 3
 3         | 1
 3         | 2
 3         | 3
```

Where `idcustomer` and `idbranch` are foreign keys to the tables `customers` and `branches`

Since you aren't using databases, the relations between the classes `Customer` and `Branch` can be built this way :

```
class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTelNo { get; set; }

    public var Branches = new List<Branch>();
}

class Branch
{
    public Guid BranchID { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchAddress { get; set; }
    public string BranchTelNo { get; set; }

    public var Customers = new List<Customer>();
}
```

Then, in the `Main` method, I would be using 2 lists for the customers and the branches.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var branches = new List<Branch>();
    var customers = new List<Customer>();

    /* You can still of course hardcode some branches ... */
    branches.Add(new Branch
    {
        BranchID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        BranchName = "lidel1",
        BranchAddress = "ejbyvej 27",
        BranchTelNo = "55223366"
    });
    branches.Add(new Branch
    {
        BranchID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        BranchName = "lidel2",
        BranchAddress = "kirkevej 45",
        BranchTelNo = "77885544"
    });
    branches.Add(new Branch
    {
        BranchID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        BranchName = "lidel3",
        BranchAddress = "kirkevej 12",
        BranchTelNo = "553366611"
    });

    /* ... and some customers */

    customers.Add(new Branch
    {
        CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CustomerName = "John Smith",
        CustomerAddress = "somewhere",
        CustomerTelNo = "0123456789",
        CustomerEmail = "john.smith@example.com"
    });
    customers.Add(new Branch
    {
        CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CustomerName = "Jane Doe",
        CustomerAddress = "Elsewhere",
        CustomerTelNo = "9876543210",
        CustomerEmail = "jane.doe@example.com"
    });
    customers.Add(new Branch
    {
        CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CustomerName = "Foo Bar",
        CustomerAddress = "anywhere",
        CustomerTelNo = "4242424242",
        CustomerEmail = "foo.bar@example.com"
    });
}
```

Now there's some branches and some customers but there's no relation yet between them.

You can build a method in the branche class to add an **existing** customer.

```
class Branch
{
    //Some properties...

    //The customer already exists and is used as parameter
    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        this.Customers.Add(customer); //the reference to the customer is added to the list.

        /*
         * Now, since we're in a Mant-To-Many relation,
         * we have to add the current branch to the newly added customer
         */

        customer.Branches.Add(this);
    }
}
```

And we can do the same for the Customer class, but it's not needed :

```
class Customer
{
    //Some properties...

    //The branch already exists and is used as parameter
    public void AddBranch(Branch branch)
    {
        this.Branches.Add(branch); //the reference to the branch is added to the list.

        /*
         * Now, since we're in a Mant-To-Many relation,
         * we have to add the current customer to the newly added branch
         */

        branch.Customers.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Of course, when you've added a branch in the customer object and you're adding the current customer in the branch, don't do `branch.AddCustomers(this);` otherwise, there's will be an infinite loop because a method will call the other one.

Now, let's add *Jane Doe*, the second customer, into the *lidel3* branch, the 3rd one.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Some code already written ...

    branches[2].AddCustomer(customers[1]);
}
```

The same way we can add the branch *lidel2* to the customer *John Smith*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Some code already written ...

    customers[0].AddBranch(branches[1]);
}
```

It's now your job to write the left of the code to let the user to add new customers, new branches, and to create relations between them.

Extra :

To avoid `goto`, I'd use that logic :

```
int choice = 1; //default arbitrary value to make sure the while condition is true

while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 4) //condition is true if user input is 1 2 3 or 4
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n1: Add Customers:\n2: Search Customer:\n3: Delete Customer:\n4: Display total no of customers in All Lidel Branches:\n5: Press enter to exit:\n");
    Console.Write("Your input is: ");
    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("***************************");

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            //some code to handle the case 1
        break; //use break to leave the switch case instead of goto

        case 2:
            //some code to handle the case 2
        break;
        //And so on ...
    }
} //When while condition is false, the loop is exited
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have one question what if i make a new class Organisation and then put the branch and customer list in there.  And in branch I put the Association list that hold the Id of branch and customer to show association. Then how can execute this idea? what are your views?

Comment: You don't need to build a list to hold the association of both IDs. That's easier to loop through a collection. If, for some reasons, you have to change an ID of an item (this is bad practice), you'll have to roam every list to make sure the id is replaced everywhere. The same if you remove an item.

Comment: If you want to get the list of customers who are in branch N, you'll have to roam the association list to get the IDs of the customers, then roam the customers to find those IDs. Using collections, you just have to roam the branches to find the one with id N, then you have directly the list `branches[N].Customers`

Comment: Association list is more a database design

Answer (score 0):

How you know if a customer already exists? By Email? By Name?
Let's consider that customers are identified by CustomerName (like you search in "SearchCustomer" method).

You have a many-to-many context (many customers can visit many branches and many branches can be visited by many customers).

So, if the same customer visits many branches, you need to know this customer. OK.

You will need to memorize every customer you add. Like you do with branches.

Something like:

`var customer = new List<Customer>()`

But you can't put this in Main Method, because is unaccessible by Branch methods. So, you can do something like:

```
- Create a global list: public static List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>(); 
// initialize list for pass ArgumentNullException on LINQ methods
```

Changing "for" in the AddCustomer method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
{

    Console.WriteLine("1-Customer Name:\n2-Customer Address:\n3-Customer Telno.:\n4-Customer Email:\n5-:Branch Name:\n");
    var customer = new Customer
    {
        CustomerName = Console.ReadLine()
    };
    //Search existing customer
    var existingCustomer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerName == customer.CustomerName);
    if (existingCustomer != null)
    { //existing customer encountered
        customers.Add(existingCustomer);
    }
    else
    {
        customer.CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid(); // generate new ID
        customer.CustomerAddress = Console.ReadLine();
        customer.CustomerTelNo = Console.ReadLine();
        customer.CustomerEmail = Console.ReadLine();
        customers.Add(customer);
        Customers.Add(customer); // add to global list
    }
}
```

However, isn't a good idea access global list from object's method. You can create a extension method or service class that does this process.

EDIT:

If you consider that is possible to add the same customer to the branch without duplicate it, you will need to find this customer in the branch customer list.
Just update the code:

```
var existingCustomer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerName == customer.CustomerName);
if (existingCustomer != null) //existing customer encountered ?
{ 
    // check if customer already added in the branch
    if(customers.Any(c => c.CustomerName == existingCustomer.CustomerName)){ 
        // do something
    }
    else {
        customers.Add(existingCustomer);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Rodrigo, it gives me a ArgumentNullException Error. And how would i use the relational database concept of many to many here in this example-

Comment: Sorry, you need to initialize the List for pass ArgumentNullException:

public static List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>().

If you use the Customer global list and you reference all the instances of customer in Branch.customers, you already using the concept of many-to-many.
SQL Database stores all customers in one table and you reference all the branch customers of this table. The difference here is, if you will use a SQL Database, you will need a third class named BranchCustomer, for this example is unnecessary.

Comment: while adding customer, it does not replace customer if it customer already exist. Actually it duplicate the customer and and make a new entity in the customer list. In reality if the customer exist then it should not duplicate it. what is your opinion?

Comment: I updated my answer (see EDIT label). Sorry if I didn't understand what you asking for. If answer isn't correct, can you show me some example of this duplicating?